# How to proportionally size images to fit dimensions of 200px x 150px thumbnail in css?

Tags: image, resize, thumbnails

I`ve tried a couple of things even using the CSS clip, but not getting it proportionally fit in the thumbnails here http://giantmango.com/arttest2-2510.

In CSS, what  is the best way and how would I proportionally resize an image to display in dimensions of a 200px (width)  x 150 (height) thumbnail?

Just checked firebug and for some reason all my img tags are always set to a height of 200 even though I have max-height set to 150...

Answer (score 2):

Use [max-height](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_dim_max-height.asp) and [max-width](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_max-width.asp). Beware that they are broken in older versions of IE. You can do

```
#myImage: {
    max-height: 150px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

**EDIT**: @tokiowp: try this. It should work (it surely does for me). So the problem with your layout comes from additional properties you may have set.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img style="max-height: 150px; max-width: 200px" src="giantmango48.jpg" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**: it turns out, looking at your source, that you are actually declaring your images with something like

```
<img src="http://giantmango.com/wp-content/uploads/giantmango78.jpg" alt="" title="giantmango78"  width="200" height="200"/>
```

Of course what you need is to remove these declarations of `width` and `height`.

Comment: @Andrea.  I did that, but it still does not seem to be resizing proportionally.

Comment: @tokyowp: In what browser are you testing?

Comment: I suggested in the body a minimal working example, where the image is resized proportionally. Probably you have additional rules or JS which break the layout.

Comment: @Andrea unfortunately, I cannot use the img tag like that because it gets the content dynamically.  I have already set the img in css to max-height: 150px and max-width: 200px, but there`s something else that I cannot figure out that is setting the height and width to both 200px.

Comment: @tokiowp: that was just an example to save space. In practice you would be writing the CSS declarations in an external stylesheet. If you try to do so, and create a page with **only** these two rules, your image will be rescaled right. I don't know what other rules are interfering, but you can try to add them one at a time until you find what is breaking your layout.

Comment: @Andrea.  I checked all entries in the css and there`s nothing that sets the height at 200px so I`m quite confused as to what is setting the dimensions.

Comment: @tokiowp: there is nothing in the css. The declaration is in the HTML itself: I have copied and pasted the last example from your site!

Comment: @Andrea.  Thank you for looking into this.  I think it`s this php function that is placing the width and height in the html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068274/how-to-code-php-function-or-set-parameters-to-return-no-height-values-for-images

Comment: Really, I have told how to solve it, so we identified the problem, and now you are off to another question. It is just rude.

Comment: @Andrea.  Please understand that I did not know my problem was a two part question.  If I solve the other one, I will be able to test your solution here.  Unfortunately, I have not been able to solve either yet and thus feel I should not accept your answer otherwise I would be lying.

Comment: @tokiowp: that's ok, anyway have a look at my (updated) answer on your other question.

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
#thumb {width:200px; height:150px;}
#thumb img {height:100%; width:100%; margin:0 auto;}
```

html:

```
<div id="thumb"><img src="tb01.jpg"></div>
```